# How to make one from multiple xlsx to select several columns in R

Tags: r, data-binding, multiple-columns, lapply, rbind

I would like to make one from multiple xlsx in R with list.files and lapply like this:

> ```
> file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
> df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
> ```

However, the files have different column-set.

file1a.xlsx:

```
V1  V2
A   A
```

file2a.xlsx:

```
V1  V3
A   A
```

file3a.xlsx:

```
V1  V4
A   A
```

I want to make one file from those three files (even whole of the files in my directory) like this:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4
A  A
A     A
A        A
```

How do I adjust the list.files and lapply??

Comment: can you please provide a reproducible example for your question

Comment: If each file contains V1, couldn't you load each one as a separate df, then use merge() to join them by V1?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a loop to read individual files. Then you can use `rbindlist` from `data.table` to merge

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = c("A"), V2 = c("A"))
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = c("A"), V3 = c("A"))
df3 <- data.frame(V1 = c("A"), V4 = c("A"))

library(data.table)
df <- rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill = TRUE)
df <- rbindlist(list(df, df3), fill = TRUE)
df

    V1 V2 V3 V4
1:  A  A NA NA
2:  A NA  A NA
3:  A NA NA  A
```

Comment: it is really very helpful for me. This is the first time to know this function. I am working with list and it is great!